# Account Required Field Missing on Lead Conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

I have Account object with custom mandatory fields. While converting a Lead when I choose a Create New Account option getting an error as Insert Failed: Required Field Missing.

As a beginner I don't know how to process. Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that there is a required field on the Account object that is not being populated during conversion. To resolve this, you need to check your mappings. Please have a look at the following documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm&language=en_US

Make sure that every field that is required on the Account object is mapped to a field on the Lead object. Then check whether every single one of these fields is populated on the Lead record before converting it to an Account.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to go about it :

1. if this mandatory field on Account is suppose have value from Lead, then map it with the Lead field.
   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm&language=en_US
2. If this mandatory field is not suppose to have value from Lead, then ensure that it has a 'default value'.
   a. either setting a default value on field itself. 
   b. or using Account Before insert trigger
3. If default value  does not solve the business purpose. 
   a. make the field mandatory using page layout only. 
   b. make the field mandatory for certain condition using validation rules/apex trigger